# why console log result or error showing 3-4 times in Browser console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

**what i want to ask is why in rect js my console is printing multiple times 0r when i get some error i am  not getting any error right now ,but when i get any error it's also printed multiple times**

**It show me same console result multiple times and when i got some error, same error will be printed 3-4 times**

> This if the file i am working in

> **I am working in React-Js**

```
const SearchBar = ({ carddata}) => {
  const navigate=useNavigate();
  let arr = [];
  
  function searchResult(e) {
    
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      if (e.target.value === "") return;
          arr = [];
          if(window.location.pathname!=='/SearchResult') navigate('/SearchResult')
            carddata.filter((result) => {
              if (`${result.heading}`.toLowerCase().match(e.target.value)) {
                  arr.push(result);
//Here is the console 
                  console.log(arr)
                }   
            });
    }
  }
return (
    <div className="flex">
      <input
        onKeyDown={searchResult}
        className="search-input w-100   br bb fw4"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search here..."
      ></input>

      <SearchIcon
        className="search-icon h2 br bb hover-black"
        style={{ fill: "red" }}
        sx={{ fontSize: 40 }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

> error in image is not related to fronted its backed so ignore it
> i added the image for better understanding:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKeVA.jpg

Comment: It seems like you maybe cut off a bit too much code when asking your question. It doesn't look like the component renders anything, and it's not clear to me how `searchResult` is ever getting called. Also, where is the component getting used?

Comment: add the error witch is shown multiple times

Comment: i added the complete file code and the file is child on app.js `carddata` is coming from app.js file through props

Comment: no i am not getting any error right now but when i get some `error` it get's printed multiple times. same with the `console.log` result

Comment: The only way your `console.log` will be called is if `searchResult` gets called, and I don't see that being called except in `<input onKeyDown>` so I might expect one per _key down_  event.  But the errors you show in your screenshot are unrelated 404 HTTP errors, presumably one for each resource your page mentions that are not found.  Your reports of what errors your are getting are vague and inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

React [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) can be the cause of multiple log messages appearing when you don't expect them because it triggers multiple renders. Try removing it from your `index.js` and see if you still have the issue, though I would recommend keeping it on.